# Robot framework and Sikuli throwing timeout exception

Tags: robotframework, sikuli

I am using Robot Framework with SikuliLibrary to compare some reports, but it is throwing timeout exception intermittently. Some runs failed only.

The error message is:

```
com.github.rainmanwy.robotframework.sikulilib.exceptions.TimeoutException: Timeout happend, could not find P(Recibo_Financeiro.png) S: 0.699999988079071
```

I created a helper keyword to use in my tests:

```
*** Settings ***
Library             SikuliLibrary

*** Variables ***
${IMAGE_DIR}                        ${EXECDIR}\\Images   

*** Keywords ***
Verify PDF
    [Arguments]                     ${PDF}
    Add Image Path                  ${IMAGE_DIR}
    Wait Until Screen Contain       ${PDF}          20
    Remove Image Path               ${IMAGE_DIR}
```

Comment: The error message seems self explanitory to me. It can not find the image in the given timeframe. Can you confirm this is incorrect?

Comment: The expected image that Sikuli will use to compare exists and it is in the correct path. But I discovered sometimes the Sikuli capture another image that it is not the focused window, the browser where my application is running. I don't know if it is a Sikuli issue or it happens because the robot was started by an Azure DevOps Agent from a release pipeline. As I was another issue that the Sikuli starts a java process and didn't close in the end of the tests only in this environment, I decided stop using Sikuli.